# How to specify entire url for a redirect result?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to redirect users to my index page using

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("app/index.html");
```

But at runtime it always looks at "home/app/index.html".

How can I get rid of the "home" part of the uri above?

This is an asp.net mvc project with an api component.  Users are using tablets.

Comment: have you tried "/app/index.html" ?

Answer (score 0):

To make it relative to the application root, use `~`, like this:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/app/index.html");
```

Always do this, which will also allow you to deploy your app in a virtual directory.